# How to implement sunburst chart in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, sunburst-diagram

I tried using highchart to implement sunburst chart but didn't work out.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/sunburst-chart"></script>

 import Sunburst from 'sunburst-chart';
 const myChart = Sunburst();
 myChart.data(data)(htmlDOM);
```

syntax:

```
data = {
 name: "root"
  children: [
  {
    name: "leafA",
     value: 3
   },
{
  name: "nodeB",
  children: [
    {
      name: "leafBA",
      value: 5
    },
    {
      name: "leafBB",
      value: 1
    }
   ]}
  ]}
```

try to below step jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/sunburst

Comment: How can you integrate this with Angular 2-9?

Comment: Do not copy-paste code from other sites as it is not helping.
You copy-paste this code from here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sunburst-chart